# Extract block of lines and get each line as a individually variable

Tags: php, mysql, text

I have a .txt file that contains a lot of lines grouped in blocks of five lines.
Something like this

What is the Capital of Italy?
 
Geography
 
Easy Difficulty
 
Madrid
 
Rome
 
Berlin
 
Venice

What is the Capital of Ukraine?
 
Geography
 
Easy Difficulty
 
London
 
Prague
 
Kiev
 
Dublin

[and many more...]

As you can see, every block is separated by a empty break line.

I want to extract each block separately where the first line to return a variable that contain the question, second line another variable with the category of question, next the difficulty of question, etc...
I need to insert each line in distinct columns of sql.

I tried with this code example

```
$file = explode(" ", file_get_contents("db.txt"));
foreach ( $file as $content ) {

    $result[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode(",", $content)));

 //var_dump($result);
echo "$content";

}
```

but is selecting the entire content of block.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Use `file()` function, it reads the file into array - each line as an array row

Comment: Why are you using  `explode()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `file` to convert the text into an array of lines, then `array_chunk` to group that array into subarrays of 7.

```
$quiz_lines = file('path/to/quiz.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
$questions = array_chunk($quiz_lines, 7);
```

You can then use `array_combine` on each chunk to set the keys:

```
$question_keys = array(
'question','category','difficulty','answer1', 'answer2','answer3','answer4'
);

foreach($questions as &$question_parts) {
    $question_parts = array_combine($question_keys, $question_parts);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A way with explode:

```
$txt = trim(file_get_contents($filepath));

$result = explode("\n\n", $txt);

$fields = ['question', 'category', 'difficulty', 'answer 1', 'answer 2', 'answer 3', 'answer 4'];

$result = array_map(function ($i) use ($fields) {
    return array_combine($fields, explode("\n", $i));
}, $result);
```

if you don't need to produce items that are associative arrays, you can remove `array_combine` and `use($fields)` in the callback function.

Note: if the file has a windows format, change `\n\n` to `\r\n\r\n`